# Mathematica not exporting gifs properly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, export, gif

I'm trying to export an image to a .gif file in Mathematica (version 7). Let's take a basic example:

```
Export["pic.gif",Graphics[{Circle[]}]]
```

There are no error messages, and a pic.gif file is in fact created, but the file's totally blank; 4 KB size, 0x0 dimensions, if I open the file no window appears.

I've tried messing with the format, such as

```
Export["pic.gif",Graphics[{Circle[]}],"GIF"]
```

and

```
Export["pic.gif",Graphics[{Circle[]}],"Image"]
```

but to no avail. Export works with other file-types (tried it with .jpg and .png with no trouble), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Version 7 is several years old
on version 9.01 (the newest) with MAC OS X this works just fine
yehuda